# why does the attr() work and text() doesn't under the same situation? jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, methods, this

1. Sorry for the poor title.
2. I have assigned selectors to my variable and chain it with `attr()` and then a different place and chain it with `text()` but the `text()` part doesn't work and I don't really understand why.

Can someone please give me a hand on what's the difference that's making it not work?

```
var alertMsg = "";
var $closestLabel = $(this).closest('label');
$(".credit-error-msg").each(function(){
    // console.log($(this).closest('label').text());
    if($closestLabel.attr('for') != "billing-unit"){  //works here
        if($(this).text() != ""){
            alertMsg += $(this).closest('label').text().toUpperCase() + "\n"; //doesn't work here that I have to write the whole thing out
            val = false;
        }
    }
});
```

see where I assigned the selector `var $closestLabel = $(this).closest('label');`
this works perfectly when I use `$closestLabel` inside the if statement but when it's inside the second if statement I have to use `$(this).closest('label').text()` because `$closestLabel.text()` would not work.

But as I can see `$(this).closest('label').text()` == `$closestLabel.text()` and `$(this).closest('label').attr()` == `$closestLabel.attr()` isn't it?

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: The value of `this` is very different outside and inside the `.each` callback function

Comment: @Phil I thought of that but the thing is, both are called inside the `.each` though

Comment: No they aren't. Your second line is **not** inside the `.each` loop

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your case the `$(this).closest('label')` inside the `each` is not the same as `var $closestLabel = $(this).closest('label');`

`this` inside the `.each` is one of the elements matched by the selector `".credit-error-msg"`

While `this` at this time: `var $closestLabel = $(this).closest('label');` is probably the `window` object.

I said probably because i don't know where in the code, within which scope, you are calling this snippet.

Comment: but I mean you can see inside the `.each` the first if statement it contains `$closestLabel.attr()` which works perfectly but inside the second if I have to write the whole thing out again. I added a bit comments to make my question more clear.

Comment: See what happens when you have this as the first line inside the `.each` statement: `console.log($closestLabel, $(this).closest('label'))`. Probably you will find out that `$closestLabel` doesn't exists here, and this `$closestLabel.attr('for') != "billing-unit"` is evaluating to `true` because `$closestLabel.attr('for')` is `undefined`, and, `undefined != "billing-unit"`;

Comment: ah, I get what you mean. the `$closestLabel` is actually returning something different. I thought of assigning `$(this)` outside of `.each` might not work so tried it and it did work as wanted. the `$closestLabel` actually gave me the output of some `input` element. which is kind of weird it still worked for what I wanted

Comment: I can understand your explanation but since it's not undefined and actually return an input element. I have 3 labels with different `for` values and somehow the `.each` does skip the one that has `for="billing-unit"`

Comment: @Dora but now you are talking about a different snippet than this one that is on your question, right? Because if you are on the root scope, `this` would be the window and `$(this).closest('label')` wouldn't return any element.

Comment: If you move `var $closestLabel = $(this).closest('label');` to inside of `.each`, then it will work.